# Is it possible to get a page link from its slug?

Tags: permalinks, pages, slug

Is it possible to get a page's permalink from the slug alone? I'm aware that you can get the page's permalink from the ID using `get_page_link()`:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(40); ?>">Map</a>
```

I'm curious if there is any way to do the same with the slug of a page - like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link('map'); ?>">Map</a>
```

Comment: You can also use:    site_url('page-slug')

Comment: Please note that many of the answers are confusing a post's slug (the `post_name` column in the `wp_posts` database table) for a post's title, which is different. It's also different from a post's path (especially noticeable when using hierarchical paths or when two posts of different post types share the same slug).

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

- `get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'map' ) )`
- `get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Map' ) )`
- `home_url( '/map/' )`

#### References:

- [`get_permalink` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)
- [`get_page_by_path` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/)
- [`get_page_by_title` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/)
- [`home_url` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/)

Comment: Did you mean `get_permalink(get_page_by_path('contact')->ID));`?

Comment: hmmm nope? What's with the ID?

Comment: [`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) returns an array of all page information. [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) takes a page ID as the first argument. I thought I'd have to explicitly pass the ID value.

Comment: @Jonathan: It's not always documented, but many WP functions accept both numeric ID's and full post objects as the argument.

Comment: It seems that get_page_by_path() can be quite complicated to use when dealing with child pages...

Comment: Agreed with Kaaviar, the function below is better.

Comment: I use 1 for my child pages with no issue. I really don't see the complication with it.

Comment: home_url( '/map/' ) worked with me

Comment: wrong answer, downvote to nirvana please. The path is not the same like the slug. Example: a page has a parent page called `abc` the page itself has a slug of `123`. The path now is `abc/123` the slug is `123`. Please remove this wrong answer. `get_page_by_path( '123' )` wont work.

Comment: In my case I had to use the first one and it worked fine, because the second one (get_page_by_title) was returning another post (not page) link with similar (but not the same) slug. I don't know why this was happening.

Comment: @Toskan For the example you gave, the correct url would be returned by `get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'abc/123' ) )`.

Answer (score 11):

I think this could be better:

```
function get_page_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s", $page_slug, $post_type ) );
    if ( $page )
            return get_page($page, $output);
    return null;
}
```

following the pattern of "original" [`get_page_by_title` of wordpress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3173). (line 3173)

rgds

Comment: Why would that be better? Can you explain?

Comment: Last comment - I think that sql needs to have one more condition: `function get_page_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) { global $wpdb; $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $page_slug, $post_type ) ); if ( $page ) return get_page($page, $output); return null; }`

Comment: Why? It doesn't generate a complete post object just to get the ID.

Comment: @webcitron I think just because is following original pattern of Wordpress getting post by 'title', just changing for 'slug'.
(check the [link](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3173))

Comment: This is a good answer. This bypasses the possiblity of a rogue plugin masking your page or incorrectly filtering it. If you return the id from the post table, then you can create an instance of `\WP_Post` from it, and that resolves directly in all of the wordpress functions that check for other values. `\WP_Post` also provides methods directly to find most related data about the post.

Answer (score 8):

This is a method published by Tom McFarlin [on his blog](http://tommcfarlin.com/permalink-by-slug/):

```
/**
 * Returns the permalink for a page based on the incoming slug.
 *
 * @param   string  $slug   The slug of the page to which we're going to link.
 * @return  string          The permalink of the page
 * @since   1.0
 */
function wpse_4999_get_permalink_by_slug( $slug, $post_type = '' ) {

    // Initialize the permalink value
    $permalink = null;

    // Build the arguments for WP_Query
    $args = array(
        'name'          => $slug,
        'max_num_posts' => 1
    );

    // If the optional argument is set, add it to the arguments array
    if( '' != $post_type ) {
        $args = array_merge( $args, array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
    }

    // Run the query (and reset it)
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $permalink = get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

It works with custom post types and built-in post types (such as `post` and `page`).

Comment: In Wordpress 6.4.2, I needed to use `post_name` instead of `name` in the query `$args`

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_path( 'map' ) ); ?>">Map</a>
```

`get_page_by_path( 'path' )` returns page/post object which can be then used by `get_page_link()` as it accepts post/page object and returns permalink.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Note that the path is not the same as the slug, necessarily.

Answer (score 3):

the accepted answer is wrong because hierarchical pages don't work like that. Simply put, the slug is not always the path of the page or post. E.g. your page has a child etc. the path will be `parent-slug/child-slug` and `get_page_by_path` will fail to find `child-slug` this way. The proper solution is this:

```
function mycoolprefix_post_by_slug($the_slug, $post_type = "page"){
 $args = array(
   'name'        => $the_slug,
   'post_type'   => $post_type,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'numberposts' => 1
 );
 $my_page = get_posts($args)[0];
 return $my_page;
}

<a href="<?php echo mycoolprefix_post_by_slug('map'); ?>">Map</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function theme_get_permalink_by_title( $title ) {

    // Initialize the permalink value
    $permalink = null;

    // Try to get the page by the incoming title
    $page = get_page_by_title( strtolower( $title ) );

    // If the page exists, then let's get its permalink
    if( null != $page ) {
        $permalink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
    } // end if

    return $permalink;

} // end theme_get_permalink_by_title
```

Use this function by

```
if( null == theme_get_permalink_by_title( 'Register For This Site' ) ) {
  // The permalink doesn't exist, so handle this however you best see fit.
} else {
  // The page exists, so do what you need to do.
} // end if/else
```

Comment: The title is not the same as the slug.

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but kind of...

You can do this:
`<?php $map = get_page_by_title( 'map' ); ?>`
`<a href="<?php echo get_page_link('$map->ID'); ?>">Map</a>`

That's how I do it :-)

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: The title is not the same as the slug.