# Environment independent way to link to certain pages on frontend

Tags: permalinks, page-template, git

On the site I'm working now on there's a number of links hardcoded into templates, such as

- Privacy and cookies
- Registration policy
- Search help

and so on.

The pages that are linked to these don't have any special design, they just inherit the default page layout.

The project I'm working on uses GIT and a workflow with multiple environments (several locals for different developers, staging, production). On all of those DBs usually are completely independent and non shared or synchronized.

What is the best way to link to these pages on frontend? I've thought about three options for now of which I'm currently using the latter one.

1. If I hardcode links to them just by referencing an ID of a page (via `get_permalink` for example) then on staging the ID might not be the same and the link will be broken. Also the page is not reassignable which might not be good.
2. If the project uses some kind of custom fields plugin like ACF or Metabox.io we might use that to create global fields per each link to allow editors to reassign them.
3. The pages can be linked via creating a custom template and then retrieving the link to the first page (thanks to `'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template'` WP_Query parameter) that uses this template. This solution is not optimal because it spams the project with potentially increasing number of duplicate templates that are all empty and don't serve any meaningful function as a part of theme.

So the question is, is there a better way to do the same thing in a native and flexible manner? Has somebody had experience solving the same problem?

Comment: sounds like you are overthinking it, or at least it is not clear what difficulty you are afraid facing. So the DBs are different, so what?

Comment: The fact that the DBs are different means that IDs for the same page to link to (called, let's say, Registration policy) will be different in each environment. And a link that (in case with `get_permalink`) worked on your local will stop working on staging or production.

Comment: so what?? as @laxmana said, just get something to select the pages, whatever you feel like (options are better performance but if you cache the page it makes little difference

Comment: ... and every user is responsible to configure his own special setup

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that option as you can see from the question description. What is unknown is that if there's an easy and native technique for doing this job, as hardcoding links into templates seems as a thing that is pretty common for many web projects. Native theme options may be too time consuming solution for this in some cases while installing a metabox/options plugin may also be an overkill if a project doesn't use any custom fields.

Comment: hardcoding anything is usually just stupid in the long run. writing proper code always takes more time, which is usually offset very quickly by not having bugs and wasting hours on WTF moments

Comment: ... obviously some things need to be hardcoded. what are those depend on the project, but generally links to pages do not fall into that category

Comment: Well hardcoding or not, it can be called in some other manner, but how would you avoid putting a link in footer to a predefined page called, say, "Privacy and cookies" if a client wants you to? That's a pretty much common thing to do.

Comment: In general hardcoding page links is a bad practice. Imo you should never ever do it, whatever the project is, small or big. As @Mark Kaplun said proper code always take more time but in the long run it worth it. It should be a habit.

Comment: How should this be done then? I mean, frontend wise, how do you permanently place a certain link to a certain page in a predefined place on a page if it's required by the client/layout? Note that by hardcoding I mean using one of the 3 methods mentioned above.

Comment: And yeah, of course if the page which is linked to is non existent we would hide the markup for the link.

Comment: Another way is to create a footer menu and let again the user decide which pages will be shown through admin panel.

Comment: Creating a menu is preferable if we talk about several links within a semantically uniform group, but what if there's only one link.

Comment: There is no different if there is one or many pages. It's the same. It just provide a way to add dynamic pages to the footer. Semantically a group can contain one element.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to create Theme Options and let the administrator decide which page is each one, with a dropdown for example.

This way you can get the selected page no matter the environment.

Comment: Thanks! This kind of answers the question as it's a native alternative to creating a global field via a custom field plugin or a theme options framework. A bit menacing as the native theme options way requires a lot of custom coding but may be OK if an optimal code is found and can be just reused then.

Comment: With ACF you can create this kind of option in one minute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'slug-goes-here' ) )
2. get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'title-goes-here' ) )
3. home_url( '/slug-goes-here/' )

Any of the above will work for you, thiw way you can avoid using post IDs but as long as the slug/title stays the same it will work.

[Is it possible to get a page link from its slug?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/is-it-possible-to-get-a-page-link-from-its-slug)

Comment: That's another way, but it's just not safe/flexible enough. Editor can change both slug and title, and then the link will be broken. Anyway, thanks for a fresh suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my own answer after some research. Here are the best options, to my mind, that allow to keep the solution relatively flexible and fast to implement, and a solution that I've ended up with. I've struggled to find a solution which could be, while keeping the advantages above, native as well.

1. If standalone links (let's not call them hardcoded as this creates some confusion evidently) are used on permanent basis in a theme and the site makes use of custom fields — one easy solution could be to create a field. I'm not sure how it could be designed — should it be repeater? checkbox? should it be global? remains to be clarified.
2. If standalone links are just few, 1 or 2 — we can simply use native custom templates; a couple of empty templates that inherit generic page design from, say, `page.php`, arguably, won't do any harm. This is not a scalable solution, though.

The third — final — solution that I'm using now is not native, but still employs the custom templates mechanism. It uses a method for registering custom templates without actually creating them described [here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin) — I changed the code provided there a bit to allow setting template names from theme ([github](https://github.com/certainlyakey/page-templater)).

So, basically, if you've got a standalone link somewhere in layout that should always stay in a certain place and should lead to a page created via admin — you provide a "virtual" custom template filename/title in a hooked function, associate this custom template with a page via `Template` admin setting and then grab the link to this page with `_wp_page_template` meta-key post query.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

1- `get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'slug' ) )`

2- `get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'slug' ) )`

3- `home_url( '/slug/' )`

Function `get_page_by_path` and `get_page_by_title` returns the `Post Object`.

**References:**

1. **[get_page_by_path](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/)**

`get_page_by_path( string $page_path, string $output = OBJECT, string|array $post_type = 'page' )`

2. **[get_page_by_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/)**

`get_page_by_title( string $page_title, string $output = OBJECT, string|array $post_type = 'page' )`

**Update**

You can get page/post from the template you have selected.

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'custom-template.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->ID.'<br />';
}
```

Above code returns the array of post objects of the pages that has a custom-template.php template selected.

If you just wanted out the page ids in return then you could try out `get_posts` function

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-special.php'
);
$pages = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $pages as $page ) 
   echo $page . '</br>';
```

**Reference:** [Get page id by template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167186/get-page-id-by-template)

Comment: I see your rationale. But slug is not constant, client could change it any moment and  break the link without even knowing it.

Comment: @certainlyakey I have updated my answer. Hope you will be able to solve your problem.